# switch display:none based on weekday

Tags: javascript

As my last question got deleted i will try to be a a little more specific in what the issue at hand is.

I have a div class by the name of budbox3, this div shows a timer displaying for how long the customer can still order with a guarantee of shipping the same day.

that is achieved with the following code.

```
var timer = null;

   function tick( )
   {
var msg = document.getElementById("countdown");
var now = new Date();
var yr = now.getFullYear(); var mon = now.getMonth(); var dy = now.getDate();
var startat = new Date(yr,mon,dy,12,0,0);
var endat = new Date(yr,mon,dy,24,59,59);
if ( now.getTime() > endat.getTime() ) 
{
    startat.setDate( startat.getDate() + 1 ); // next game is tomorrow
}
if ( now.getTime() >= startat.getTime() && now.getTime() <= endat )
{
    msg.innerHTML = "";
} else {
    var sec = Math.floor( ( startat.getTime() - now.getTime() ) / 1000 );
    var min = Math.floor ( sec / 60 );
    sec %= 60;
    var hr = Math.floor ( min / 60 );
    min %= 60;
    if ( min < 10 ) min = "0" + min;
    if ( sec < 10 ) sec = "0" + sec;
    msg.innerHTML = hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec + " Endnu";
}
}
tick(); // immediate start
timer = setInterval( tick, 1000 ); // every second
```

the challenge for me now is to get the above div class to only run on weekdays, as we cannot at the moment send out shipments during the weekends.

i have tried unsuccessfully with the following code, perhaps someone can be of assistance?

```
var now = new Date();
var day = now.getDay();

function SetDivContent() {

if (day==0||day==6) {
    $(".budbox3").css("display","none !important");
}
else if (day==1||day==2||day==3||day==4||day==5) {
    var timer = null;

    function tick( )
    {
        var msg = document.getElementById("countdown");
        var now = new Date();
        var yr = now.getFullYear(); var mon = now.getMonth(); var dy = now.getDate();
        var startat = new Date(yr,mon,dy,12,0,0);
        var endat = new Date(yr,mon,dy,24,59,59);
        if ( now.getTime() > endat.getTime() ) 
        {
            startat.setDate( startat.getDate() + 1 ); // next game is tomorrow
        }
        if ( now.getTime() >= startat.getTime() && now.getTime() <= endat )
        {
            msg.innerHTML = "";
        } else {
        var sec = Math.floor( ( startat.getTime() - now.getTime() ) / 1000 );
        var min = Math.floor ( sec / 60 );
        sec %= 60;
        var hr = Math.floor ( min / 60 );
        min %= 60;
        if ( min < 10 ) min = "0" + min;
        if ( sec < 10 ) sec = "0" + sec;
        msg.innerHTML = hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec + " Endnu";
        }
    }
    tick(); // immediate start
    timer = setInterval( tick, 1000 ); // every second
}
}
```

Comment: Instead of `$(".budbox3").css("display","none !important")`, use `$(".budbox3").hide()`.

Comment: That said, what is the issue with your current code?

Comment: two things.

first of all the timer is not running as it should.

second the budbox3 is still visible on days it should not be.